# Two separate interfaces or one extended by another: To DRY or not to DRY

Tags: inheritance, typescript, interface, redux, state

Coming from typeless language JavaScript to a typed TypeScript, you start using interfaces. Sometimes simple questions on how to structure an app turn into violent discussions with my team mates:) We are building React+Redux+TypeScript app, and we have two "things": **Application state for User** (user representation inside Redux store) and **API response of User** (Describes JSON API response), both of them have interface, which, as of now, are the same, but this could change. The mapping is done using some custom function:

```
const mapUserApiToState = (user: IUserAPI): IUserState => { ... }
```

Since it's an early stage, and there will be plenty of interfaces to write there are two or three paths we could take:

**(1) Separate each interface into their own respective file**. But you will have to repeat same attributes for each interface which violates the DRY principle.

```
// file1.ts
interface IUserState {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  kids: number;
}

// file2.ts
interface IUserAPI {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  kids: number;
}
```

**(2) Just extend one interface with another**. That way you won't need to repeat yourself, but this would imply that one interface extends another, when in reality they look the same, but are for completely different purposes

```
// file1.ts
interface IUserState {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  kids: number;
}

// file2.ts
interface IUserAPI extends IUser {}
```

**(3) Create some third abstract interface**. But this creates one more file with interface that shouldn't be used (where would you use IUser?)

```
// file1.ts
interface IUser {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  kids: number;
}

// file2.ts
interface IUserState extends IUser {}

// file3.ts
interface IUserAPI extends IUser {}
```

**(4) Quit waisting time on trivial things. YAGNI.**

Comment: couple of questions i'd ask myself in this case: are the two interfaces **likely** to diverge? does the application falls apart if they're not in sync? Can you merge them instead of abstracting them even more, to have 1 interface instead of two or three?

Comment: @mseimys In the 3rd case, why would you say `IUser` isn't going to be used? That interface already is part of the other interfaces `IUserState` and `IUserAPI`. Won't you use it to hold structural information for both derived interfaces? I mean, you will modify that interface whenever there are common changes, right?

Comment: @Leone yes, I would hold common properties in this `IUser` interface, but I think
it is not wise to use it everywhere, in such case other two are completely useless
in the first place, hence my question :) Well my example may look trivial,
but imagine having tens of complex attributes,
like `points: [{ isVisible: true, title: "Title", tags: [1, 2, 3]}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debate we decided to use TypeScript's `typeof` feature and decided to duplicate the enumeration of variables, but instead of using two interfaces we use the value of default application state as a definition for our type. So it's not the same as two interfaces, but really makes more sense.

```
interface IUserAPI {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    kids: number;
}

const defaultUserState = {
    id: 0,
    name: "Unnamed",
    kids: 0
}

type IUserState = typeof defaultUserState
```